# YouTube iframe API undefined error on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, api, youtube, internet-explorer-9

I got this javascript error only on IE9 when used YouTube `iframe` API with `html5=1` passed to the API. I passed `html5=1` to force all IE browsers to display HTML5 video player instead of the Flash player.

```
SCRIPT5022: undefined



html5player-new.js, line 1847 character 180
```

I'm wondering if anyone ever experience this error and how to solve it.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about that specific error, but IE9 has really poor support for HTML5, so it could be that.

Comment: If you have this `<script src="html5player-new.js"/>` change to this  `<script src="html5player-new.js"></script>`

Comment: If not please provide code on `line 1847 character 180` please